# espacios entres varios items en una vista. MVC

Tags: c#, html5

desde un foreach envío a mi vista varios items del modelo, y me muestran sin problema, pero busco que se puedan colocar con espacios considerables.

**Mi código:**

```
 <tr>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td> <label> <strong> @item.Name </strong>  </label> </td>
        }
    }
</tr>
```

**como se ve la vista**

Cargar Disponibilidades Asignar Silla Estudiante    Terminado

busco tener más espacio entre "Cargar disponibilidades" "Asignar silla estudiante" "Terminado"

Comment: Mete el contenido de cada columna en un div y a este via css asignale un margin

Answer (score 0):

No intentes hacerlo con espacios en blanco en el código HTML, hazlo con CSS.  Ejemplo:

```css
.mi-tabla td {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="mi-tabla">
  <tr>
    <td>Cargar Disponibilidades</td>
    <td>Asignar Silla Estudiante</td>
    <td>Terminado</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Primer Item</td>
    <td>Segundo Item</td>
    <td>Tercer Item</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```